# Converting small-ish Oracle long raw values to other types

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table that contains a field of LONG RAW type that contains ASCII character data.  How can I write a query or view that will convert this to a more easily consumed character string?  These are always going to be single-byte characters, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

`select ...., to_lob(long_raw) from old_table`

(http://www.psoug.org/reference/convert_func.html)

or

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(b)
```

(http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5342).

Answer (score 0):

I found this quote:

> In Oracle9i, you can even:
>
> alter table old_table modify ( c clob
>   );
>
> to convert it.

See here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1037232794454

**Edit**

The max length of a varchar2 column is 4000. Is that too short?

Comment: An existing and pretty brittle application currently uses this table, so I'd prefer not to modify the existing table for fear of knocking down the house of cards.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this works well on CLOB data types.  I would believe the same would hold true for LOB types.

```
create or replace function lob2char(clob_col clob) return varchar2 IS
buffer varchar2(4000);
amt BINARY_INTEGER := 4000;
pos INTEGER := 1;
l clob;
bfils bfile;
l_var varchar2(4000):='';
begin
LOOP
if dbms_lob.getlength(clob_col)<=4000 THEN
dbms_lob.read (clob_col, amt, pos, buffer);
l_var := l_var||buffer;
pos:=pos+amt;
ELSE
l_var:= 'Cannot convert.  Exceeded varchar2 limit';
exit;
END IF;
END LOOP;
return l_var;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
return l_var;
END;



INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (NEWCOLUMN) SELECT RTRIM(lob2char(OLDCOLUMN)) FROM OLDTABLE;
```