# Oracle Long Raw Problem

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00932, ora-00997

select  utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(DCFILE) hexchar from T_FILE

ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

```
select  to_char(DOC_FILE) hexchar from T_DOC_FILE
```

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG BINARY

My column type long raw, how to make selected varchar2 ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426079/converting-small-ish-oracle-long-raw-values-to-other-types

Answer (score 2):

Oracle introduced their LOB datatypes in version 8.0, well over a decade ago.  LONG and LONG RAW have been deprecated since before the Millenium (in favour of CLOB and BLOB respectively) precisely because working with LONGs is a pain in the neck and LONG RAWs doubly so, as you are now finding.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Your logic seems confused.  LONG RAW is intended for storing binary data (images, documents, etc) so rendering it as text is unlikely to produce satisfactory results.