# C# - How to get oracle long raw type value

Tags: c#, oracle

How to get long raw type value with C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644051/oracle-long-raw-problem

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.  Please learn to be patient.  SO is not a support forum and it is not meant to handle emergencies.

Comment: @APC: I don't think it's a dupe... although I'm not sure what he's asking in the other question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any code, I don't know how much you know. I'm going to assume you already understand how to execute a query and get back a result set using OracleDataReader.

There is one gotcha with LONG and LONG RAW columns. **You must set the `InitialLONGFetchSize` property of your `OracleCommand` to a non-zero value.**

The default value of `InitialLONGFetchSize` is zero, which means no data will be retrieved for LONG or LONG RAW columns. If you set it to -1, all data will be retrieved . You might not want to do this for large values. If you set it to anything above zero, that's how many bytes will be intially fetched and cached.

You should read [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featData.htm#i1007197) for `InitialLONGFetchSize`, because there are some other details you need to know.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Code to solve this issue.

```
          Byte[] img;
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("Select Image as BLOBDATA FROM tbltestImage ", con);
        command.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;
        OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        con.Close();
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            if (dt.Rows[0]["BLOBDATA"].ToString() != "")
            {

                img = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["BLOBDATA"];


                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);

                pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;

                pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            }




        }
```

Comment: In case someone is using the System.Data.Common classes then a type casting will be necessary:

((OracleCommand)selectCommand):InitialLONGFetchSize := -1

selectCommand is an IDbCommand object and OracleCommand is from the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client namespace.