# Use utl_file.fopen to read an image without name

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have some images stored in the database but I don't have the names of these images.

Does anybody have any idea about how can I read these images using `utl_file.fopen()` ?

Comment: If the image is stored in the database why do you need to open it on the file-system?

Comment: the image stored in database is in LONG format. I am able to open an image in c# code, casting it into byte[].. but some how I am not able to open the image stored in long format. That is why I am just trying to find a way to open that image in oracle itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTL_FILE is a package for manipulating OS files from within a PL/SQL package.  You have images stored in a database column, presumably a BLOB.  Consequently UTL_FILE is entirely the wrong tool for the task.

In fact the database has virtually no interest in the contents of BLOB columns and Oracle do not often much in the way of functionality for rendering images.  What you need to do is issue a query to select the relevant column and return it to a client tool which can display the image.

---

> "the image is stored in LONG format (neither long raw nor blob). "

Then you're really out of luck.  There's even less built-in support for LONGs than there is for LOBs.

Oracle deprecated LONG infavour of LOB a long time ago precisely because the LONG datatype was too awkward to work with.  LOBs were introduced in Oracle8, over fifteen years ago, and there is really no reason to still be using LONGs.   Which I appreciate isn't helpful in your current predicament.

---

Incidentally, what do you have in mind when you say:

> "any other method which can be used to view this image in oracle
>   itself"

"Oracle itself" is a datastore.  Retieving and viewing data is the job of a client; this can be a developer's tool such as SQL*plus or TOAD, or an application.  I don't know of any IDE which renders images; if there are any it is highly unlikely they will have an image stored in a LONG.

So I think your only option is writing something yourself in C# (if that's your chosen language).  In which case you should [read this answer on working with LONGs in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655950/146325)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the image is stored in LONG format (neither long raw nor blob). Can you suggest me any other method which can be used to view this image in oracle itself.

Comment: Right now, I have the data of some images stored in long format & I want to find a way to see them, whether using TOAD,SQL Plus or using c# code, anyhow.