# Missing <Long> type in Oracle via oracle connection execute reader c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

I execute command "**select * from ws_access_log**" in pl/sql developer.

[image]

when my asp.net c# program execute command

```
command = new OracleCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = cmd;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
connection.Open();

dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

connection.Close();
```

but missing log_description (**Long**) with no error message appeared, I have tried all of this '*foreach loop*' for a single record, '*oracleDataAdapter.fill*' and '*dataTable.Load*'

[image]

Thank you in advance and I hope for your help :)

> Solution for this --> Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644572/c-sharp-how-to-get-oracle-long-raw-type-value). Hopefully that helps you. –  @sstan

Comment: Sorry, but your c# code shows nothing useful.  Where is the query, where is the exact error message that you got, what are you actually trying to accomplish?  I will give you a hint though... Oracle's `Long` type is deprecated, and should be avoided, if possible, in favor of the `LOB` types.  It's possible that this is what's causing you grief.

Comment: my query statement `SELECT *  FROM WS_ACCESS_LOG L  ORDER BY L.LOG_TIME DESC` in c#

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644572/c-sharp-how-to-get-oracle-long-raw-type-value).  Hopefully that helps you.