# How can i read Oracle LONG RAW and show that in picture box?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a big problem in c# windows application,in the my oracle database has a this record:

```
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1000000000000000000000000000000003E0...
```

that record save into Long Raw data type into oracle database,i want read that record and show that in picture box,for more explain that record image save into  oracle database.How can i write code for that purpose?

Comment: You need to clarify how that data save in database first, if it is `base64` string, you are duplicate with [C# Base64 String to JPEG Image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18827216/1050927)

Comment: @Alex Oracle form builder save with ole into database

Comment: Then please refer this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644572/c-sharp-how-to-get-oracle-long-raw-type-value)