# Oracle data_default returns nothing

Tags: c#, oracle

I have one C# project and i want to get DATA_DEFAULT colum value in USER_TAB_COLS table but i always just get "" if the DATA_DEFAULT column is null or not.
My code:

```
string query = $"SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_DEFAULT,DATA_TYPE,DATA_PRECISION,DATA_LENGTH,NULLABLE FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableName}'";
                OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(query, connection);
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable columnsTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
                    foreach (DataRow row in columnsTable.Rows)
                    {
                        string columnName = row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
                        string dataType = row["DATA_TYPE"].ToString();
                        int dataLength = 0;
                        if (row["DATA_PRECISION"].ToString() != "" && 
   Convert.ToInt32(row["DATA_PRECISION"].ToString()) == 1)
                        {
                            dataLength = Convert.ToInt32(1);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            dataLength = Convert.ToInt32(row["DATA_LENGTH"]);
                        }                       
                        bool nullable = row["NULLABLE"].ToString() == "Y";
                        string defaultvalue = row["DATA_DEFAULT"].ToString();

                        Colums.Add(new Colum(columnName, dataType, dataLength,nullable,""));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The `DATA_DEFAULT` column has data type `LONG`, so you probably need some variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655950/266304), setting `InitialLONGFetchSize`.

Comment: Alex Poole thank you for your help.