# Convert the Highvalue of user_partition in varchar2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
select SomeFunction(HIGH_VALUE)  
  from user_tab_partitions ;
```

while getting the scheme ,

```
desc user_tab_partitions;

Name                   Null Type         
---------------------- ---- ------------ 
TABLE_NAME                  VARCHAR2(30) 
COMPOSITE                   VARCHAR2(3)  
PARTITION_NAME              VARCHAR2(30) 
SUBPARTITION_COUNT          NUMBER       
HIGH_VALUE                  LONG()
```

HIGH_VALUE column of user_tab_partitions is stored as LONG datatype..still i am not able to convert that in varchar2..
I am able to If i store that Highvalue using select into clause..but i want to pass that highvalue in function and get result back as varchar2..I have written below function but it doesnot work..

```
create or replace
function SomeFunction(high_val LONG raw) 
return varchar2
is
   lHigh_value     LONG;
   strDate_clause  VARCHAR2(100);
begin
   lHigh_value := high_val;
   strDate_clause := lHigh_value;
   return strDate_clause;
end;
```

so please help me for solving the problem..
thnks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the accepted answer in this SO entry...

[Converting small-ish Oracle long raw values to other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426079/converting-small-ish-oracle-long-raw-values-to-other-types)

and use

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2
```

http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5342

Comment: this is also not wroking...select partition_name ,to_lob(high_value) high_value from user_tab_partitions ;

Comment: this is also not working...select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HIGH_VALUE) from user_tab_partitions;

Comment: "not working" is not very helpful. What error messages are you getting etc.?

Comment: while using this..select partition_name ,to_lob(high_value) high_value from user_tab_partitions ;..SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG

Comment: select UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HIGH_VALUE) from user_tab_partitions; SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"

Comment: This article by Tom Kyte might well provide the answer for you: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:839298816582

Comment: Also this one here is written specifically about the issues of accessing the LONG columns in Oracle's data dictionary: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:839298816582

Comment: Is it only the data dictionary you are accessing? If it is you aplication tables then you should consider updating the LONG columnns to LOBs as LONG was deprecated many years ago (no idea why Oracle keeps using them in the data dictionary though).

Comment: smethng like below is working.FOR .. IN select..from tbldataconfig where key like '.NoTables5min%' 
FOR x IN (SELECT .., high_value
FROM user_tab_partitions WHERE table_name =key_val)
LOOP END LOOP;END LOOP;.but in this cse 2 loops iterates.need smething like below:FOR key_val,max_no_tbl IN select key,value from tbldataconfig where key like 'MaxNoTables5min%' 
insert into tbl_marked_for_delete SELECT table_name, partition_name, high_value FROM user_tab_partitions WHERE  table_name like ''%'||key_val ||'5min||'and somefunction(HIGH_VALUE)<(SYSTIMESTAMP-numtodsinterval(max_no_tbl, 'DAY'))
LOOP